# How to implement a Stack in LISP language

Tags: stack, lisp, implementation

I am still learning Lisp language and I need to understand how to implement a stack with Lisp (Need push-pop-peek functions.). In addition I have found this code when I am searching for help. But I am not sure if it is working properly.

```
(defstruct stack
  elements)

(defun stack-push (element stack)
  (push element (stack-elements stack)))

(defun stack-pop (stack)(deftype Stack [elements])

(defun stack-empty (stack)
  (endp (stack-elements stack)))

(defun stack-top (stack)
  (first (stack-elements stack)))

(defun stack-peek (stack)
  (stack-top stack))
```

Comment: This code looks _mostly_ OK, although there's no implementation of  `stack-pop`. (I'm assuming that `(deftype Stack [elements])` is supposed to be a separate form, though I'm not sure what it's supposed to do.)  The code is more or less OK, though.  Why aren't you sure whether it's working properly?  Have you tried it?  Tested it?  Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: The real problem that I have is when I run this code in Sbcl I can only see STACK and STACK-PUSH.I can't see POP and PEEK.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp lists are actually functional stacks in and of themselves.

(cons a l) pushes a to the stack l.

(car l) returns the first element (a peek).

(cdr l) returns all but the first element (a pop).

Comment: Yeah but where is the actual implementation in this code that is what I don't really understand..?

Comment: In this case, there isn't a separate implementation. The point was that stacks are already there for you in Lisp- cons is the same as push, car is the same as peek, cdr is the same as pop.

Comment: @VolkanÖztüzün It's worth noting that in "Lisp lists are actually _functional_ stacks in and of themselves," the word "_functional_" is used as in the sense of functional programming.  Rather than treating `push` and `pop` as methods of some object with mutable state, think of them as functions that return a new stack like the old one, but with one addition or one less element, respectively.  E.g., `stack1 = (1 2 3)`, `stack2 = (push 0 stack1) = (0 1 2 3)`, and `stack1 != stack2`.

Comment: Hmm that sounds right.So I don't need to write stack1 = (1 2 3) on my actual code because they are already there for me as Greg said.I just need to worry about testing them in my CMD(I mean where I use the Sbcl)?